# ASP.NET MVC Ajax Comment Add - Rebind comments section

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Ajax.BeginForm to post comment.

How should I update the Comments section area to incorporate this new comment?

I am displaying comments on the page using the typical "foreach(Comment comment in Model.Comments)"

Answer (score 1):

You probably return something from your Action, right? Make it, for example, a partial-view with the new post in it. You then get the result in a javascript return handler (that can be specified in the `AjaxOptions` parameter of `Ajax.BeginForm(...)`) and insert it into the DOM where appropriate. There's an excellent example of how to do this (and a lot of other cool stuff) in this [video tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC21/) by Phil Haack at PDC 2008. (Tip of the day: if you want to learn ASP.NET MVC, it's really worth the time...)